# WPF: Binding Line values to TextBox values

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, converters

I have a line and textbox in my WPF project as below:

```
<Line Fill="Red" X1="{Binding ElementName=TxtStartLine1, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource PointConverter}}" />
```

also to code c# code for PointConvert is:

```
public class PointConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return 0;
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I want to change X1 property of line by textbox value but I get this error from VS designer:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error
>
> An object of the type "System.Windows.PointConverter" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter". ALPRX   F:\Projects\ALPR\repos\license-plate\ALPRX\FindiLpdParams.xaml  283"
>   update 1:
>   Header of .XAML file where I define converter is listed in comments.

Comment: Can we see the XAML where you create the `PointConverter` resource? It looks like you are creating an object of the wrong type, which happens to have the same name as your class, but that one is in the `System.Windows` namespace. Try `<local:PointConverter x:Key="PointConverter" />` instead. `local:` will be your own namespace -- what namespace did you define your own `PointConverter` class in?

Comment: <Window x:Class="ALPRX.FindiLpdParams"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PointConverter x:Key="PointConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

Comment: Please add code to your question. It's very hard to read in a comment. But yes, there's the problem: `xmlns:local="schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation"` is not a local namespace. That needs to be the local namespace where your converter is defined: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ALPRX"` most likely.

Comment: Where do you define the resource that points to the PointConverter? Your XAML should also have something like "<local:PointConverter x:Key="PointConverter"/>" in the Window/UserControl's Resource section.

Comment: Also, you do realize your PointConverter always returns 0 currently. Otherwise, this code seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett thank you. At those moment, because of my low Internet speed, I couldn't update the question (I mean adding code to question). I fix the problem. I defined converter in another place.